# how to calculate the average of bunch of lines that contains floating values in python

Tags: python, loops, average

I am trying to write a program in python that opens the file and reads through the file, looking for some pattern. After that i have to parse the identified lines and extract the float value from the each line and then calculate the average of all the lines. This is what i have written so far

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
sum = 0
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count = count + 1
        number = float(line[19:])
        for num in range(number):
            sum = sum + num
        average = sum/count
print "Average spam confidence:", average
print "Done"
```

But i am getting this error `start must be a integer on line 12` and i can't seem to understand why. I am relatively new to python and i am wondering if i get some help regarding this error.

Comment: `range` expects an integer argument to count upto from 0. You are giving it a float value. Do you need to just sum the numbers and average them after the `for line in fh` loop?

Comment: Yes but i need to parse the lines first to extract the numbers and then count, sum and finally get the average of them. If i don't give range then i am getting another error 'float values cannot be iterable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to loop over that line, do you? I assume your data looks like this: PATTERN:FLOAT if that's the case try this.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
sum = 0
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count = count + 1
        number = float(line[19:])
        #for num in range(number):
        sum = sum + number
        average = sum/count
print "Average spam confidence:", average
print "Done"
```

if your data on the other hand looks like this PATTER:FLOAT-SOMESEPERATOR-FLOAT...

then you should split them apart before converting them.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
sum = 0
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        numbers = line[19:].split("SPERATOR")
        for num in numbers:
            count = count + 1
            sum = sum + num
        average = sum/count
print "Average spam confidence:", average
print "Done"
```

LG

Comment: My pattern looks like the former `X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475`. However when i tried your solution for that pattern i am getting this error: name 'num' is not defined on line 12`

Comment: sry, not num... forgot to change it, should be number

Comment: It worked. I should i noted that by myself. But anyway, thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to find the sum of consecutive numbers from 1 to n you can use the identity

```
sum = (n*(n+1))/2
```

Then if you need the average of this you effectively divide by n and are left with the identity

```
avg = (n+1)/2.0
```

However if your value n is a float then it seems unlikely you would want to count up to the float.  If you have a list of floats then you can find the average by simply summing over the list:

```
sum = 0
for n in my_list:
    sum += n
avg = sum/ len(my_list)
```

Comment: Maybe use `sum = 0.0` for clarity and safe-checking in the last case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop over the float value, you only have to sum up the different float values, to calculate an average.

Here is a solution with a counting iterable:

```
class CountingIterable(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iter(iterable)
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.iterable:
            yield item
            self.count += 1

    def __int__(self):
        return self.count

with open(fname) as fh:
    values = CountingIterable(
        float(line.split(':')[1])
        for line in fh
        if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"))
    average = sum(values) / int(values)

print "Average spam confidence:", average
print "Done"
```